# I can not change the background-color value of wp: meta_value of content.xml

Tags: css

I can not change the background-color value of `<wp: meta_value>`

I'm trying to change by css the value of background-color in the class that is automatically generated by the Visual Composer called:

> vc_custom_1510991353768

with this:

```
.vc_custom_1510991353768 {
    background-color: #006e48 !important;
}
```

But, my **styles.css** of child theme does not recognize because it is owned by , according to the code referenced below:

```
<wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css]]></wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[.vc_custom_1510991353768{background-color: #22355b !important;}]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

I already try this ([Custom colors for post rows based on post meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106919/custom-colors-for-post-rows-based-on-post-meta-value) ), but this dont work for me.

I need help, thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I got it by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537370/override-inline-css thanks guys

Comment: XML files don't have colours. I really don't understand what you're trying to do. What is content.xml?

Comment: it's the import file from theme that i buy from themeforest, but this deny the change of color with styles.css of my child theme

Comment: I got it by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537370/override-inline-css thanks guys